# ReactJS: Duplicates arising while creating mouse over event

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, jsx

I am trying to create cards in my react project.[My Current Project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2fbAo.png)
The problem is that I have created React Components that reuse the same class, and when I am implementing a mouseOver event to switch between classes to achieve a transition effect, the effect gets applied on all classes that share the same CSS class. How can I avoid this? 
I believe that the  tag is causing my problems, how do I split the functionality without much redundancy in the code?

Please note that I am a beginner.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './OneHome.css'
import OneCard from './OneCard.js'
class OneHome extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.someHandler = this.someHandler.bind(this);
        this.someOtherHandler = this.someOtherHandler.bind(this);
        this.state={
            buttonStyleClass:"CardButton",
        };
        }
    someOtherHandler() {
        this.setState({buttonStyleClass : "CardButton"});
    }
    someHandler() {
        this.setState({buttonStyleClass : "CardButtonHover"});
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className ="FlexContainer">
                <OneCard >
                    <h1 className="CardTitle"> Part One </h1>
                    <div className="CardSeparator"> </div>
                    <button className={this.state.buttonStyleClass} onMouseEnter={this.someHandler} onMouseLeave={this.someOtherHandler}> Click Here</button>
                </OneCard>
                <OneCard > 
                    <h1 className="CardTitle"> Part One </h1>
                    <div className="CardSeparator"> </div>
                    <button className={this.state.buttonStyleClass} onMouseEnter={this.someHandler} onMouseLeave={this.someOtherHandler}> Click Here</button>
                </OneCard>
                <OneCard > </OneCard>
                <OneCard > </OneCard>
                <OneCard > 
                <h1 className="CardTitle"> Part One </h1>
                    <div className="CardSeparator"> </div>
                    <button className={this.state.buttonStyleClass} onMouseEnter={this.someHandler} onMouseLeave={this.someOtherHandler}> Click Here</button>
                </OneCard>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default OneHome;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no identification maintained in your code to set the current element that is being hovered. In your `someHandler`, on hover, you can pass index or reference or some sort of keyword to identify the current card that is being hovered. You can then do ternary check to append the class. Rather than maintaining the classnames in state, you can append/remove them directly as shown.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './OneHome.css'
import OneCard from './OneCard.js';

class OneHome extends Component{
    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.someHandler = this.someHandler.bind(this);
        this.someOtherHandler = this.someOtherHandler.bind(this);
        this.state = {
            activeCard: 0
        };
    }
    someOtherHandler() {
        this.setState({
          activeCard: 0
        });
    }
    someHandler(activeCardIndex) {
        this.setState({
          activeCard: activeCardIndex
        });
    }

    render(){
        return (
            <div className ="FlexContainer">
                <OneCard>
                    <h1 className="CardTitle"> Part One </h1>
                    <div className="CardSeparator"> </div>
                    <button className={this.state.activeCard === 1 ? 'CardButtonHover' : 'CardButton'} onMouseEnter={() => this.someHandler(1)} onMouseLeave={this.someOtherHandler}> Click Here</button>
                </OneCard>
                <OneCard > 
                    <h1 className="CardTitle"> Part One </h1>
                    <div className="CardSeparator"> </div>
                    <button className={this.state.activeCard === 2 ? 'CardButtonHover' : 'CardButton'} onMouseEnter={() => this.someHandler(2)} onMouseLeave={this.someOtherHandler}> Click Here</button>
                </OneCard>
                <OneCard > </OneCard>
                <OneCard > </OneCard>
                <OneCard > 
                <h1 className="CardTitle"> Part One </h1>
                    <div className="CardSeparator"> </div>
                    <button className={this.state.activeCard === 3 ? 'CardButtonHover' : 'CardButton'} onMouseEnter={() => this.someHandler(3)} onMouseLeave={this.someOtherHandler}> Click Here</button>
                </OneCard>

            </div>
        );
    }
}

export default OneHome;
```